# WPF custom control question

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

i've done this before but i cannot find my old code.

how do you embed a window inside a window.

let say i created a custom form and saved it as Window1.xaml, and want to embed it in Window2.xaml, without copy and pasting the xaml code.. TIA

EDIT: i think my question is somewhat misleading, i'll rephrase it.

i have this Window1.xaml i added custom headers and background images/colors.

then in Window2.xaml, i want Window1 to be a custom control and embed it here.

not sure if its Content Presenters, still googling for the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should make use of Pages or usercontrols in such cases. This way you can navigate to other parts/pages/controls defined in application. CodeKaizen is right , you can't host a window inside another window

Answer (score 3):

You can't host a WPF Window inside another WPF Window, but you could move the content from one Window to another:

```
var window1 = new Window1();
var window2 = new Window2();

var content = window1.Content;
window1.Content = null;
window2.Content = content;
```

Note that you set `window1.Content` to `null` or else you get an exception, since the content will have a visual parent otherwise.

**UPDATE**
It appears all you need to do is to copy all the XAML between the `<Window></Window>` tags in `Window1` into a new `UserControl`, then host that user control in `Window2`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do that - however, you shouldn't put the user interface directly into a window, use a normal control (either custom or user) instead and reuse that in your windows.

Comment: i think it really isn't putting the window directly, i want it to be like a custom control

Answer (score 0):

I know you can do it in code behind

```
//Window you want to show
Window1 child = new Window1(); 

object content = child.Content;
child.Content = null;

//Where to show
this.grid1.Children.Clear();    
this.grid1.Children.Add((UIElement)content);
```

Hope helps!

Comment: Not bad, but you could make this code a bit tighter (declare `content` to be `UIElement` or `var` and there is no need for `grid1`).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you really want a UserControl.  Change Window1's type from Window to UserControl and then put that UserControl in Window2.